# Sonar Qube: Checkmarx vulnerability Reflected_XSS_All_Clients for Spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, sonarqube, xss

We are getting CheckMarx Vulnerability: Reflected_XSS_All_Clients issue for our spring boot application in Service class although:

1. We are validating the particular parameter using java validation pattern
2. We remove xss component from all our input parameter in one filter class.

Above two step ensures protection from Reflected XSS issue, still sonar qube is raising this critical issue.

How can I overcome this issue?

Comment: Please don't post the same text multiple times

Comment: welcome to SO @Arpita Dasgupta. To better help you, can you please share some of the affected code snippets from both the source and the sink?